# How to get the line separator of current os easily in Scala?

Tags: scala, newline

I remember in Java, we do it like this:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

How to do the same in scala? Is there a better(easier) way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
scala> import util.Properties
import util.Properties

scala> Properties.lineSeparator
res14: java.lang.String =
"
"
```

Answer (score 4):

Both **`scala.util.Properties.lineSeparator`** and **`System.lineSeparator`** will do the same job.

`System.lineSeparator` will directly call Java method which has to find property in systems props:

```
lineSeparator = props.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Here is the result:

```
scala> System.lineSeparator
res0: String = 
"
"
```

It falls back to default Java props if none found.

Similarly, `Properties.lineSeparator` will call:

```
def lineSeparator = propOrElse("line.separator", "\n")
```

which eventually calls:

```
System.getProperty(name, alt)
```

Result is the same:

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.lineSeparator
res2: String = 
"
"
```

So they both get line separator from Java props. The only difference is how they get defaults. I don't know why it's implemented this way :). It's like they don't trust that Java will have correct default in this case.